# Weird dse hive integration in DSE 4.7

Tags: hadoop, hive, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I'm trying to run Hive query over existing C* table.

Here is my C* table definition:

```
drop table IF  EXISTS mydata.site_users;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS appdata.site_users (
        user_id         text,
        user_test_uuid  uuid, --for testing purposes, if we can use it in queries, there could be some serde problems?
        user_name       text,
        PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
        );
```

Here is my external hive table definition:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE c_site_users(
        user_id string, user_test_uuid binary, user_name string)
        STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.cql3.CqlStorageHandler'
        WITH SERDEPROPERTIES( "cassandra.ks.name" = "mydata",
        "cassandra.cf.name" = "site_users",
        "cql3.partition.key" = "user_id",
        "cassandra.cql3.type" = "text, uuid, text"
      );
```

I've inserted data into C* table using cqlsh:

```
cqlsh:appdata> select * from site_users;

 user_id | user_name | user_test_uuid
---------+-----------+--------------------------------------
   user2 |      Ivan | 51569760-10e6-11e5-af86-23fdaf275fb9
   user1 |    Sergey | 51542660-10e6-11e5-af86-23fdaf275fb9
   user3 |     Johan | 5157a8d0-10e6-11e5-af86-23fdaf275fb9

(3 rows)
```

Now I try to run the same query using **dse hive**

```
vagrant@dsenode01:~$ dse hive

Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/dse/hive/hive-log4j.properties
hive> select * from c_site_users;
OK
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.io.IOException: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.UnavailableException: Not enough replica available for query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 required but only 0 alive)
Time taken: 13.297 seconds
```

So weird!
C* table is ok, data is there, I can query it, but dse hive complains. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so answer is dead simple. I need to run dse with hadoop enabled on each node. I have 3 nodes and RF=1. And only one node was with HADOOP enabled. I turned HADOOP on all 3 nodes and it works from both sides: query external table backed by C* table and C* table directly since DSE implicitly updates metastore with C* tables.